# Creating a static page from img src file

Tags: php

I edited Nicolas d'Haussy's php gallery script(http://bolgallery.free.fr/) to render what I need. My issue is that when I click the photo, It loads the jpg file.

I would like the script to create static pages from each uploaded photo - ie. 1.jpg => 1.php

I currently have to do this manual, and thought there might be a way to have this dynamic - site I am referring to, http://photos.alexandergutierrez.info/

Here is the file I currently have, http://db.tt/dEfe2wJ

Hope this all made sense since I am not developer.

Comment: Why don't you link to a file calles `image.php` or similar and pass the jpg as parameter like `image.php?image=1.jpg`? Then you only need to code the php file once and you don't need to generate multiple scripts.

Comment: Forgot to mention I am no developer. I don't follow your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you would need to edit the *a* element on line 112 to be to the correct place. Then I would say the rest can be completed with a simple .htaccess file and a php script. For the htaccess file to work you must be using apache. Below is the code for it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*).php$ view.php?img=$1 [L]
```

Then all you have to do is make a php file called view.php that looks at the GET value for img and load that image however you want. This would allow you to do something like *testimage.php* which would load *testimage*, which would then load `testimage.png` or whatever.

Comment: I forgot to mention I am no developer. I do not know how to change line 112 to href a .php file. I am currently using the .htaccess file to hide the ".php" from the files I manually create - 1.php, 2.php, etc. Where I have the first(RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f), second and third rule in place. I'll have to research the last rule. Last, would your recommendation change the URl? I would like the URL to be like what I currently have.